# Android: UI old interface

Tags: android, android-layout

For some Activity I'm using @Theme/Dialog, but this appears like old UI 2.3.
If I set the Theme of the Activity in the Manifest as Holo/Dialog, then this work fine, but of course this will not work with older devices.

How to force Holo Theme when available?

I tried with a custom MyTheme, but all the activity that have @android:style/Theme.Dialog, continue to appear like old theme.

My activity look like below:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".audio.TempoManager"
        android:label="Tempo Manager"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

if I change it to @android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog then on old device the activities will not be open as dialog but as simple activity.

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/holo-everywhere.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

refer to this blog post. it answers your question: [holo-everywhere](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/holo-everywhere.html)

**mainly:**
1. you write a `theme.xml` file defining a `MyTheme` in `res/values/` for all pre-3.0 android versions.
2. write a `themes.xml` file defining the `MyTheme` in `res/values-v11/` for 3.0+ android versions.
3. in the `AndroidManifest.xml` define the application theme to be `MyTheme`.

the first theme inherits from `@android:style/Theme`.
the second theme inherits from `@android:style/Theme.Holo`.

Answer (score 0):

If ICS is available on the device it will default to Holo,

If you want to create for instance the ICS font universally on all devices you will need to provide the ttf font file asset and use it in a custom textview and/or buttons etc..

Comment: xBroak, I was sure too about it, but I don't know why it's not working like this.

Comment: Use the following in your manifest <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="14" /> also, make sure the theme is set in ure XML for definite, as the documentation states there is no reason it shouldnt default.